# Issue while configuration oracle apex + ords + tomcat 9

Tags: oracle-apex

I already configured Ords 20.0 with tomcat 9 , it works fine but some icons not come properly and got error message .
[image: error message]

[image: these icons appear in local installation]
[image: and that's on tomcat , icons not come correct]

Answer (score 0):

There is a script that you're missing to load the images.
Double check the installation guide. And if it's an upgrade you also need to run the script.

That combo of versions work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After paste the images in route /i/. Run this command

```
java -jar ords.war validate
```